# Find top N items for each key based on a sum of 2 other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table (Amazon Aurora) where each row contains a timestamp, an account ID, and an amount (in dollars) of account A and an amount (in dollars) of account B. Rows look like this:

```
1462791600     123     100     200
```

For each timestamp, I want to find the top 10 invoices (those with the highest dollar amounts of accounts A + B). Can I do this in MySql? I don't have much experience with SQL, but here is what I was trying to do:

```
SELECT ts, id, account_A + account_B AS account_sum
FROM table
GROUP BY ts
ORDER BY account_sum
LIMIT 10
```

The issue with the above SQL is that it doesn't give me a top 10 for each time stamp. I am not sure how to write part in SQL.

Comment: There's only one row. So what's the problem?

Comment: That one row is an example row. There are many rows in the database.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why a `group by` would be necessary for this query.  However, it is tricky to do this in MySQL.  Here is a method using variables:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (@rn := if(@ts = ts, @rn + 1,
                        if(@ts := ts, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM table t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @ts := -1) params
      ORDER BY ts, (account_A + account_B) DESC
     ) t
WHERE rn <= 10;
```

This is not obvious.  The formulation above uses variables to mimic the `ROW_NUMBER()` function available in almost all other databases.

It enumerates the rows for each timestamp.  The outer query simply chooses the top 10 for each timestamp.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the help. This is pretty complex and I don't understand all the variable assignments yet. I tried running the statement and I do get the top 10 counts, but not the top 10 counts for each individual timestamp.

Comment: If it helps, I'm using MySQL with Amazon Aurora.

Comment: Are you sure the timestamps are *exactly* the same?  Also, be careful about `=` versus `:=`.